# Image gallery with mobile view optimization

Tags: views, media

I'm using Drupal 7, and I want to have a photo gallery.

When viewing the gallery using mobile phone or ipad, I wish to have the photos shown like facebook photo gallery:

1. image will auto resize according to screen size
2. when user slides the image to left or right, it will shows previous or next photo

Is there any module which can achieve the above effect?

Answer (score 0):

You may try out the [Photoswipe module](http://drupal.org/project/photoswipe) (dev).

Comment: Is there any other module which is not under development? As we need a more stable module. Thanks in advance